# Integrate barcode reader generate/read with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can anyone have idea regarding Barcode Reader with Codeigniter?

The system should generate barcode which is store in DB, and able to read it.

Comment: Please add more information and some code, this is not a place to make other people think for you, it is for solving problems

Answer (score 1):

You can use third party php barcode generator like one provided on gith hub https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator
using this you can create print function like one given below. this is a small snippet you have to add content of your own here

```
<?php
function print()
{
include(APPPATH.'third_party/php-barcode-generator/src/BarcodeGenerator.php');
include(APPPATH.'third_party/php-barcode-generator/src/BarcodeGeneratorPNG.php');
include(APPPATH.'third_party/php-barcode-generator/src/BarcodeGeneratorSVG.php');
include(APPPATH.'third_party/php-barcode-generator/src/BarcodeGeneratorHTML.php');
$generatorPNG = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorPNG();
$generatorSVG = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorSVG();
$generatorHTML = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorHTML();
$data = $this->model_name->model_function_name();   
foreach ($data as $value) {
echo '<img style="width: 200px;height: 50px" src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($generatorPNG->getBarcode($value->column_name, $generatorPNG::TYPE_CODE_128)).'">'
}
}
?>
```

Above the model returns the data which are fetched from the database using which it is converted into the barcode and displayed as an image. Hope this snippet will help you to develop your own,